# Is there a closed, convex subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, such that any proper, closed, convex shape in the plane is a section of $C$?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

To be precise, by a section of $C$ I mean the intersection of $C$ with a hyperplane. I want every proper, closed, convex subset of the plane, up to translation and rotation, to be appear as sectiond. So, for example, I want both the unit disc and the disc of radius $8.45$ to appear as sections.

It was recently brought to my attention that there is a closed convex *cone* in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the set of conic sections is "dense" amongst the proper, closed, convex sets of the plane (dense in exactly metric, I do not know). This astonished me and motivated the above question. I would be very surprised if the answer is yes, and am kind of expecting some argument which shows that such a $C$ obviously cannot exist. But as I've just learnt, convex subsets can be highly exotic.

If the answer is positive a bonus question would be if it can be arranged so that every closed, convex subset of the plane, up to translation and rotation, appears exactly *once* as a section.

Comment: No, half planes are closed and convex. And yes, $C$ would have to unbounded.

Comment: Oh, alright....

Comment: you know a reference for your surprising cone?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I heard this in a talk by an expert

Comment: Huh.   What expert and approximate title?

Comment: As a side remark, the answer is no in case you remove the word "closed" from the question.  A 3-dimensional convex set has at most $2^{\mathbb N}$ sections while there are $2^{2^{\mathbb N}}$ different "shapes".

Comment: @WillJagy Guillaume Aubrun

Comment: Does some plane section have to be the entire plane? That looks problematic.

Comment: I guess that is kind of a special closed, convex set, but I don't think including it will be more problematic than including, for example, all the other unbounded closed convex sets like a half-plane.

Comment: Aubrun is still active on MO. I placed a comment there with a link to your question here, also asked for a standard reference.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423174/are-the-polyhedral-cones-the-only-examples-of-cones-that-remains-closed-when-the#comment1087838_423174

Comment: Well, this time of year people travel...  Go to his university web page, there is a book with Szarek , could easily have your cone example https://case.edu/artsci/math/szarek/

Comment: Specifically, it looks to me that the only convex subsets of three-space containing a plane are Cartesian products of that plane and an interval.

Comment: I think you’re right. A closed convex set is an intersection of closed half spaces and if one of its sections is the plane any hyperplane corresponding to those halfspaces has to be parallell to it.

Comment: I’ll change the question to proper, closed convex

Comment: Presmumably "dense" means dense in Hausdorff metric, or equivalently Vietoris topology. As Hwang says maybe you really want to focus on **compact** convex sets, or maybe even those contained in the unit disk. I feel like the space of compact convex subsets of unit disk is locally connected hence Peano (an image of $[0,1]$), so at least that gives you a $C$ which is not necessarily convex.

Comment: Let $X$ be the space of affine isometric embeddings from $\mathbf{R}^2$ to $\mathbf{R}^3$ and $Y$ the space of convex compact subsets of $\mathbf{R}^2$, equipped with Hausdorff distance. I can imagine an argument showing impossibility along the following lines: if there was such a convex set $C$, there would be a onto and locally Lipschitz map from an open subset of $X$ to $Y$ ; this is not possible since $X$ is finite-dimensional while the space $Y$ is infinite-dimensional. (Here I consider only sections though the interior on $C$; tangent planes produce at most countably many sets).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not answering the question, but clarify on the denseness result alluded to: there is a convex cone $C \subset \mathbf{R}^3$ with the following property. If you fix an affine hyperplane $H$ not containing zero, a compact convex set $K \subset H$ and $\varepsilon >0$, then there is a linear transformation $f : \mathbf{R}^3 \to \mathbf{R}^3$ such that the intersection $f(C) \cap H$ is at Hausdorff distance $< \varepsilon$ from $K$.

These linear maps $f$ induce projective transformations on $H$ ; so in other words there is a planar convex body $L$ whose orbit under the projective group is dense (you only want to consider projective maps which do not send points of $L$ to infinity). This can exist because projective transformations do not respect distance, so you could hide the projective image of any convex set you want in an arbitrary small neighbourhood. I wrote a note about this some years ago.
http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/homes-www/aubrun/recherche/dense-projective-orbit.pdf

You cannot achieve this with $\varepsilon =0$ if $C$ is a cone. For example you could not see both a triangle and a square as sections (through the interior) of the same cone, since they are not projectively equivalent.

I would also be surprised if a convex set with your property exist.

Comment: Thank you for giving an answer here! I see, you link to a reference also.